# ask Automatic Number does not increase when Save Button Clicked

Tags: vb.net

I need a help for my case.

I have a procedure for automatic number of id_staff, when the form load, the automatic number is working but when the save button is clicked, the automatic number is not working, I must close the form and load the form again to make it happen.

Please help me..

Below is my code.. Any suggest would be highly appreciated

```
Sub id_barang()
    Call koneksi()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from tb_lokasi order by id_barang desc", conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()
    If Not dr.HasRows Then
        txt_id.Text = "BG-001"
    Else
        txt_id.Text = CStr(Val(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(dr.Item("id_barang").ToString, 4, 3)) + 1)
        If Len(txt_id.Text) = 1 Then
            txt_id.Text = "BG-00" & txt_id.Text & ""
        ElseIf Len(txt_id.Text) = 2 Then
            txt_id.Text = "BG-0" & txt_id.Text & ""
        ElseIf Len(txt_id.Text) = 3 Then
            txt_id.Text = "BG-" & txt_id.Text & ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and here the code of saving button

```
 Private Sub cmd_simpan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd_simpan.Click
    If txt_kode.Text = "" And txt_lokasi.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Data masih belum lengkap", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Simpan Data Barang")
        txt_kode.Focus()
    Else
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert into tb_lokasi values('" & UCase(txt_id.Text) & "','" & UCase(txt_kode.Text) & "','" & UCase(txt_lokasi.Text) & "')", conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Call id_barang()
        Call bersih()
        Call tampilbrg()
        Call aturtampil()
        txt_kode.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

for the database, I am using Ms.Access

Comment: Please don't say something is not working without giving us detail of the problem.

Comment: the problem is, when the save button is clicked, it saves the data into database, but the automatic number is not increase. the automatic number will increase when I close the form and run it again. What I want is, when the save button is clicked, the data is saved into database and the automatic number is increase automatically

Comment: Please check that `Dim id = dr.Item("id_barang").ToString()` gives you the id that you expect. If it does then try `txt_id.Text = String.Format("BG-{0:000}", Val(id.Replace("BG-", "")) + 1)` to see if it updates correctly.

Comment: I have try what Enigmativity has suggest, but it does not solve my problem. My problem is not about the id_barag it self, but it is about the procedure. When the button save is clicked, the id_barang will not increased automatically. It will increased only if I close and reopen the form again. Thank you.. Would be appreciated if any one will give me a suggest...

Comment: You need to show the code for loading the form then.